# NodeJS, how to debug Parse Error at TLSSocket.socketOnData on GET request?

Tags: json, node.js, debugging, https, get

I'm quite new to NodeJS and have been trying it out on AWS Lambda writing a simple Alexa service to tell me the temperature in my house. I've hit an issue that has me stuck - when I try to communicate with an https endpoint to query some data for a home automation thermostat - my Node application terminates with an error:

```
Error: Parse Error
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

This is a fairly simple GET request via https, and the providers of the endpoint have no issues using Python. I tried moving my code to a local Node setup on my laptop and am still having the problem (so its not AWS). As it's https and a service outside of my contral I can't easily wireshark the traffic to spot if the response is corrupt in some subtle way - however I tried using Browsify to convert the code to run in a web browser (where I can use wireshark) and of course it then works, and I can see nothing odd about the json response I then get.

I've tried using the response module instead of the core https libraries in node but I still get the same underlying error.

I'm stuck about what I can do - and have no clue how to debug this. It strikes me as either a formatting issue or a timing issue - but i'm not sure how to approach this. Ideas anyone?

My code looks like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var crypto = require('crypto');

function executeHttpRequest(path, data, method, username, password) {

    var encodedLogin = getLoginString(username,password);
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);

    var requestOptions = {
        host: 'hub-server.domain.co.uk',
        port: 443,
        path: path,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedLogin
        }};

    var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(response) {

        var body='';
        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        response.on('error', function(err){
            console.log(method + " error: \n", err.stack);
        }); 

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("read data: " + chunk);
            body += chunk 
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log("end data");
        });

    });

    request.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('request error: \n' + err.stack);
    });

    console.log("sending request:" + JSON.stringify(requestOptions));
    console.log("with data: " + stringData)

    request.write(stringData);  
    request.end();
    console.log("closed request")
}
```

When run in node I get the following output

```
sending request:{"host":"hub-server.domain.co.uk","port":443,"path":"/zone/1","method":"GET","headers":{"Cache-Control":"no-cache","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Basic bWFjdGEyOmY0OWZiODJlYTcyNWYzNDgwMTViODVjZTNlZmIyYmY1MWE4ZmI3YWUxMzJmZTRkNDk4OGEc"}}
closed request
request error: 
Error: Parse Error
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

I get the same error with a similar PUT command. Interestingly if I miss out a parameter when using PUT, and the server replies with a JSON error, the above code works and show me JSON documenting the error. Similarly, if I use an invalid URL or bad AUTH I correctly get an appropriate status code.

My code also seems to work if I trying hitting https://www.google.com and do a search.

Obviously something is up - but how can I either correct my node code, or advise the authors of the endpoint?

Answer (score 4):

## The response has both `Content-Length` and `Transfer-encoding: chunked` headers (which is an error)

Using a debugger I found the http parser is actually showing an error code: HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH - searching more on google about this, I see that several others have experienced this (interesting, all to do with home automation) - and the conclusion in these threads is that later versions of Node have become more strict about the HTTP spec due to security concerns. Armed with this error code, searching reveals two similar cases to mine (e.g. [http.get Parse Error, code: 'HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525715/http-get-parse-error-code-hpe-unexpected-content-length)) the conclusion was that there was a response with both Content-Length and Transfer-encoding: chunked headers existing together (which is an error). My response doesn't have this error, however I wonder if the declared content length is wrong or if there is a spurious cr/lf in the response somewhere. I'm hoping I might be able to debug this hypothesis in IntelliJ

[image: IntelliJ debugging a node application]

Comment: how can we reproduce the issue ? I have tried with duplicate headers but doesn't reproduce.