# http.get parse error code: 'HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH' only from windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, http

Hi I am doing http get request in nodejs code running on windows machine but same code is working fine in Linux machine . but i'm getting an error like

```
 Error: Parse Error
  at Error (native)
  at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:359:20)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20) bytesParsed: 220, code:     
  'HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH'
```

my request is

```
 http.get('http://192.168.6.102/web/data/abc.json', function(res) {
           var flatresponse = res;
               // console.log("success::",flatresponse);
    var body = '';
    statusCode = res.statusCode;
   console.log("In get data.json",res.statusCode,res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
       console.log("In get body chunk",body);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        try{                


        if(statusCode == 200){          
       console.log("In get body chunk",JSON.parse(body));

        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Exp::",e);
    }
 });
}).on('error',function(err){
 console.log("error:::",err);
})
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525715/http-get-parse-error-code-hpe-unexpected-content-length

Comment: instead of `JSON.parse(body)` use `JSON.Stringify(body)`

Comment: No friend, i tried that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if anyone stumbles on it - the error might come from a duplicate Content-Length error sent back by the server.
As a workaround, try https://github.com/creationix/http-parser-js - this solved the issue for me.
Add
process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser = require('http-parser-js').HTTPParser;
when your client starts.